# My code is reading the textbox just once

Tags: c#, textbox

The problem is that my code is just reading the Textboxes just the very first time, wheneaver I do any change to the Textboxes it doesn`t read the new ones.

This is the code of the form with 2 textBoxes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   double tb1, tb2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form1 forming = new Form1();
        Reading objR = new Reading(forming);

        tb1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        tb2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);


       textBox4.Text= objR.mAdd(tb1,tb2).ToString();
       textBox5.Text = objR.mAdd2().ToString();

    }
}
```

And the class where I´m trying to read the textboxes is this:

```
class Reading
{
    double _tb1, _tb2;



    public Reading(Form1 form)
    {
      this._tb1 = double.Parse(form.textBox1.Text);
      this._tb2 = double.Parse(form.textBox2.Text);

    }
    public double mAdd(double a, double b)
    {

        return a + b;
    }      


     public double mAdd2()
    {
        return _tb1 + _tb2;
    }
 }
```

I think that `Reading objR = new Reading(forming);`reads the TextBoxes but they are read just once, When I Click my Button again it is just giving me the same info, I added the method mAdd to make sure the textboxes are being used correctly.

What can I do to actualy read the newest data in the Textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

First, it's overkill to pass the entire form in to your  `Reading` class' constructor.  Why not just have a constructor with two `double` arguments?
Second, if you **have to** pass the form, then remove the `Form1 forming = new Form1();` and replace the next line with `Reading objR = new Reading(this);`

Comment: It´s just a test I did, I need to use more types of variables. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   double tb1, tb2;
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Reading objR = new Reading();

        tb1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        tb2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);

       textBox4.Text= objR.mAdd(tb1,tb2).ToString();
       textBox5.Text = objR.mAdd2().ToString();
}

public class Reading
{
    public double Reading(double a,double b)
    { 
        _tb1= a;
        _tb2 = b;
    }
    public double mAdd(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }      
    public double mAdd2()
    {
        return _tb1 + _tb2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is you are passing a NEW instance of Form1 to your reading class and not the instance where the textboxes you are changing.

Just to add to ffa's answer.

With this, the return value of reading class' mAdd and mAdd2 will be the same.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    tb2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    Reading objR = new Reading(tb1, tb2);
    textBox4.Text= objR.mAdd(tb1,tb2).ToString();
    textBox5.Text = objR.mAdd2().ToString();
}


class Reading
{
    double _tb1, _tb2;

    public Reading(string tb1, string tb2)
    {
        this._tb1 = double.Parse(tb1);
        this._tb2 = double.Parse(tb2);

    }
    public double mAdd(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    } 

    public double mAdd2()
    {
        return _tb1 + _tb2;
    }
}
```